# View confirmed attendees from past events on web3 app; Javascript; imports from React and Apollo Client - how to fix a Syntax error in code

Tags: javascript

The page for my web3-based event application works fine until I go into my "past events" and click "attendees." When I do that, I get *Syntax error: Unexpected token*.

The issue is specifically on line 86 of my code, ***for (let i = 0; < event.confirmedAttendees.length; i++) {***. In VS Code, I have 4 errors, all of which point to this line. The errors are "parsing error: unexpected token", 2 "identifier expected" errors, and 1 "expression expected."

I've checked the code against the GitHub repo I forked the entire project file from, edited it, and now it all matches.

I'm new to coding with no previous JS experience. I've been scratching my head on this one all day. I have no idea what the issue is.

Here is the entire code from my [id].js file. The issue is with line 86.

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Head from "next/head";
import Link from "next/link";
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";
import client from "../../../apollo-client";
import { ConnectButton } from "@rainbow-me/rainbowkit";
import { useAccount } from "wagmi";
import connectContract from "../../../utils/connectContract";
import formatTimestamp from "../../../utils/formatTimestamp";
import DashboardNav from "../../../components/DashboardNav";
import Alert from "../../../components/Alert";

function PastEvent({ event }) {
  const { data: account } = useAccount();

  console.log("event", event);

  const [success, setSuccess] = useState(null);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(null);
  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);

  const confirmAttendee = async (attendee) => {
    try {
      const rsvpContract = connectContract();

      if (rsvpContract) {
        const txn = await rsvpContract.confirmAttendee(event.id, attendee);
        setLoading(true);
        console.log("Minting...", txn.hash);
  
        await txn.wait();
        console.log("Minted -- ", txn.hash);
        setSuccess(true);
        setLoading(false);
        setMessage("Attendance has been confirmed.");
      } else {
        console.log("Ethereum object doesn't exist!");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      setSuccess(false);
      // setMessage(
      //   `Error: ${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_TESTNET_EXPLORER_URL}tx/${txn.hash}`
      // );
      setMessage("Error!");
      setLoading(false);
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const confirmAllAttendees = async () => {
    console.log("confirmAllAttendees");
    try {
      const rsvpContract = connectContract();
  
      if (rsvpContract) {
        console.log("contract exists");
        const txn = await rsvpContract.confirmAllAttendees(event.id, {
          gasLimit: 300000,
        });
        console.log("await txn");
        setLoading(true);
        console.log("Mining...", txn.hash);
  
        await txn.wait();
        console.log("Mined -- ", txn.hash);
        setSuccess(true);
        setLoading(false);
        setMessage("All attendees confirmed successfully.");
      } else {
        console.log("Ethereum object doesn't exist!");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      setSuccess(false);
      // setMessage(
      //   `Error: ${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_TESTNET_EXPLORER_URL}tx/${txn.hash}`
      // );
      setMessage("Error!");
      setLoading(false);
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  function checkIfConfirmed(event, address) {
    // console.log(event.confirmedAttendees);
    for (let i = 0; < event.confirmedAttendees.length; i++) {
      let confirmedAddress = event.confirmedAttendees[i].attendee.id;
      if (confirmedAddress.toLowercase() == address.toLowercase()) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setMounted(true);
  }, []);

  return (
    mounted && (
      <div className="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <Head>
          <title>My Dashboard | web3rsvp</title>
          <meta name="description" content="Manage your events and RSVPs" />
        </Head>
        <div className="flex flex-wrap py-8">
          <DashboardNav page={"events"} />
          <div className="sm:w-10/12 sm:pl-8">
            {loading && (
              <Alert
                alertType={"loading"}
                alertBody={"Please wait"}
                triggerAlert={true}
                color={"white"}
              />
            )}
            {success && ( 
              <Alert 
                alertType={"success"}
                alertBody={message}
                triggerAlert={true}
                color={"palegreen"}
              />
            )}
            {success === false && (
              <Alert
                alertType={"failed"}
                alertBody={message}
                triggerAlert={true}
                color={"palevioletred"}
              />
            )}
            {account ? (
              account.address.toLowerCase() ===
              event.eventOwner.toLowerCase() ? (
                <section>
                  <Link href="/my-events/past">
                    <a className="text-indigo-800 text-sm hover:underline">
                      &#8592; Back
                    </a>
                  </Link>
                  <h6 className="text-sm mt-4 mb-2">
                    {formatTimestamp(event.eventTimestamp)}
                  </h6>
                  <h1 className="text-2xl tracking-tight font-extrabold text-gray-900 sm:text-3xl md:text-4xl mb-8">
                    {event.name}
                  </h1>
                  <div className="-my-2 -mx-4 overflow-x-auto sm:-mx-6 lg:-mx-8">
                    <div className="inline-block min-w-full py-2 align-middle md:px-6 lg:px-8">
                      <div className="overflow-hidden shadow ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 md:rounded-lg">
                        <table className="min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-300">
                          <thead className="bg-gray-50">
                            <tr>
                              <th 
                                scope="col"

                                  className="py-3.5 pl-4 pr-3 text-left text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900 sm:pl-6"
                              >
                                Attendee 
                              </th>
                              <th
                                scope="col"
                                className="text-right py-3.5 pl-3 pr-4 sm:pr-6"
                              >
                                <button
                                  type="button"
                                  className="items-center px-4 py-2 border border-transparent text-sm font-medium rounded-full text-indigo-700 bg-indigo-100 hover:bg-indigo-200 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500"
                                  onClick={confirmAllAttendees}
                                >
                                  Confirm all 
                                </button>
                              </th>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody className="divide-y divide-gray-200 bg-white">
                            {event.rsvps.map((rsvp) => (
                              <tr key={rsvp.attendee.id}>
                                <td className="whitespace-nowrap py-4 pl-4 pr-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 sm:pl-6">
                                  {rsvp.attendee.id}
                                </td>
                                <td className="relative whitespace-nowrap py-4 pl-3 pr-4 text-right text-sm font-medium sm:pr-6">
                                  {checkIfConfirmed(event, rsvp.attendee.id) ? (
                                    <p>Confirmed</p>
                                  ) : (
                                    <button 
                                      type="button"
                                      className="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900"
                                      onClick={() => 
                                        confirmAttendee(rsvp.attendee.id)
                                      }
                                    >
                                      Confirm attendee
                                    </button>
                                  )}
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            ))}
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </section>
              ) : (
                <p>You do not have permission to manage this event.</p>
              )
            ) : (
                <ConnectButton />
              )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  );
}

export default PastEvent;

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const { id } = context.params;

  const { data } = await client.query({
    query: gql`
      query Event($id: String!) {
        event(id: $id) {
          id
          eventID
          name
          eventOwner
          eventTimestamp
          maxCapacity
          totalRSVPs
          totalConfirmedAttendees
          rsvps {
            id
            attendee {
              id
            }
          }
          confirmedAttendees {
            attendee {
              id
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `,
    variables: {
      id: id,
    },
  });

  return {
    props: {
      event: data.event,
    },
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you missed the i in the for loop check in this function:

```
  function checkIfConfirmed(event, address) {
    // console.log(event.confirmedAttendees);
    for (let i = 0; < event.confirmedAttendees.length; i++) {
      let confirmedAddress = event.confirmedAttendees[i].attendee.id;
      if (confirmedAddress.toLowercase() == address.toLowercase()) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Take a look at the second line in your function:

```
// currently:
for (let i = 0; < event.confirmedAttendees.length; i++)

// missing i in the check, should be:
for (let i = 0; i < event.confirmedAttendees.length; i++)
```

Let me know if anything seems unclear regarding for loops!